# Elasticsearch warmer usage

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to understand what how exactly would warmer help us in our use case.

Say we have records for items, and items have vendor attribute.

```
{
   item_name:"item1",
   vendor_id:"abc",
   ...
},
{
   item_name:"item2",
   vendor_id:"abc",
   ...
},
{
   item_name:"item3",
   vendor_id:"xyz",
   ...
},
{
   item_name:"item4",
   vendor_id:"xyz"
   ...
}
```

We are constantly indexing new items. And most of the query is based on vender_id with different filters, and the query performance isn't idea for us. It looks like it can be optimized with warmer, which will load our filter into cache for future query.

My question is, if I set the warmer to include:

```
{ 
   "vendor_id":"abc"
}
```

Would that warm-up query speed up query for vendor_id="xyz" also? Or would the cache only contains filter for vendor_id="abc"? If not, what would be the recommended way to force all vendor_id filters are cached?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you register a warmer to warm up a query against a specific field, ES will load all the values for that fields in the respective caches (fielddata, filter, etc)

So a simple query for `"vendor_id": "abc"` will indeed load all values, which means also `"xyz"`, `"def"`, etc.

However, you need to know that warmers are going to be [removed in version 5](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/breaking_50_index_apis.html#_warmers) and they won't be anymore useful thanks to the use of [doc values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/doc-values.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to clarify, are you saying if I set doc_values=true for vendor_id, then having warmer for vendor_id won't have any effect?

Comment: Yes, should not have any effect.